# How to connect a button-click signal ("triggered" signal) with an action/slot function for a user button in a toolbar with Qt Creator?

Tags: action, signals, qt-creator, toolbar, slot

Having seen earlier existing discussion on "stackoverflow" forum about designing and managing menus and actions under an application being designed & developped under Qt Creator (see "How to connect menu click with action in Qt Creator?" : [How to connect menu click with action in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726392/how-to-connect-menu-click-with-action-in-qt-creator/5341334#5341334)), **I'm afraid I have same questions about action buttons in a toolbar I'm trying to create & populate with Qt creator...**

So, let's go !

(1) I create at least one action in the Action Editor...
(2) I drag&drop that action to the toolbar

(steps 1 & 2 are ok, no difficulties with these ones, although it is a quite unusal way of doing such things for me, because other UIM designing tools usually propose inverse steps 2 & 1 to do the same, which is more "natural" in my opinion, but, I know, many many things exist and co-exist in our world of software designing & programming...)

**=> (3) How to associate (connect) the function (which I'm going to implement) that is supposed to be called when clicking the given toolbar button ?**

I mean, how to connect the "triggered" signal for the given action (toolbar button) to the desired slot (function) to be implementing later... ? Is it possible to do such things with the "Signals and slots editor" inside Qt Creator, or do I have to call "connect()" by myself somewhere in the code to achieve this ? Many thanks in advance for any help/suggestion/detailed example for perfect beginner at this point...

In fact, I would to know wether it is possible not to call connect() by myself for such need and wether Qt Creator will create slot (function) prototype by itself or do we have to create such slot (function) prototypes by ourselves before Qt Creator can take the new slot (function) prototype into account and really assist/help user/developper in this usual/normal UIM design step / designing capability... ?

Best regards.

Alain-Pierre

Answer (score 0):

If the `QAction` is a member if your window, then the normal

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(SettingsDialog);
```

...will connect an action's `trigger` signal with an appropriately named slot method. This is normally called automatically by GUI classes created using the designer. So if the action is named `actionSomething` for example, creating a slot in your GUI class with a signature like:

```
void on_actionSomething_triggered();
```

...will mean that you don't have to manually `connect` the signals and slots.

Also, **right-clicking** on the action in the action editor and selecting 'Go to slot...' will allow you to create a slot function for any signal that the action may emit.