# QT Menu how to create a new window?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am working in QT Creator.

I would like to mention that I am beginner in this software. I succeeded to create a menu that has: Edit and Open. I would like to create a new window when " Open " from menu bar is clicked. Till now I succeeded to print a message in QMessageBox when I press Open. What is the code for linking Open clicked with a new window? Is it possible to somehow drag and drop a new window in mainwindow.ui and than link it with Open on action Open_activated()?

THX . Appreciate

P.S I AM WORKING IN UBUNTU/C++ language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the question is already answered by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518317/how-to-show-another-window-from-mainwindow-in-qt). It leaves one part open, namely how that slot is called.

Well, you answered that: the menu entry "Open" is a `QAction`. You can [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726392/how-to-connect-menu-click-with-action-in-qt-creator) that action to the slot which you just created.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too late to answer but as I am also a beginner and struggled a lot to figure out this, I would like to share a solution that worked for me and according to me this is one of the simplest solution out there for a beginner.

Follow this [link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_MainWindowTriggerAction.php). It's possible that in the future that link might not exists, hence I am writing down a detailed version, as detailed as possible because I think for an absolute beginner (like myself) it can be very useful.

1. Default mainwindow.cpp

[image: mainwindow.cpp]

2. Go to "mainwindow.ui" (or whatever .ui one has)

[image: .ui page]

3. Right-click outside the window and activate "Action Editor" if it wasn't already activated:

[image: Action Editor]

4. Right-click on the window and create "Menu-bar" and then double-clicking on "type here" you can rename it as "Open" or something which will then drop-down another box where you can again type the name you desire, let's say "message".

[image: menu-bar]

[image: type-here]

[image: menu-item message]

5. When created menu item "message" is created corresponding item will apear in the "Action Editor"

[image: message in the action editor]

6. Right-click on the "message" in the Action Editor and click "go to slot" which will lead you to the specific slot in the mainwindow.cpp:

[image: go to slot]

[image]

7. Here you can create a small window with whatever message you want to display.

[[![Window creating code][11](http://www.qtforum.org/article/32853/about-and-help-dialog-boxes.html) etc goes here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpArQ.png)][12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpArQ.png)

[image: Codes that create a mini window and display some read-only text.]

****don't forget to include "QTextEditor", go to mainwindow.h and #include "

[image]

On compiling & executing we will see :

[image: click open->message->to open new window]
[image: message window.]